# Virtual Hosts / Postfix mail log, show sending website

Tags: php, virtualhost, postfix-mta

I've been googling around for awhile now and have been unable to find any sort of solution or any information at all.

What I need to do is to configure postfix so that when one of our websites sends mail using PHP (via a contact us form or w/e) the mail log will show what the sending website was.  This way we can identify a compromised website/form, etc in case one of our IP addresses should get blacklisted.  We run virtual hosts so each server could have dozens to hundreds of websites on them.  For us to otherwise track them down manually could take forever.

Is this even possible? Perhaps its not if I couldn't find anything on google :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using PHP 5.3's new [`mail.log`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php#ini.mail.log) configuration directive.  It will allow you to define a log file where all calls to the `mail()` function are recorded, including the To address, the headers, and the full path to the script that made the call.

If you aren't running 5.3, consider upgrading to it, or to 5.4 once it's out in a few weeks.

Unfortunately this is only half of a solution.  There are numerous PHP mail libraries that speak SMTP.  If you permit local SMTP connections (as most good web hosting providers should), then users would have a way to bypass that log.

Comment: Charles, thank you for the response.  We are actually going to be running with 3 different versions of php (to start 5.1,5.2, and 5.3) eventually we'll go to just 5.2 and 5.3 so that would be helpful for that assuming we don't allow for SMTP.  Though I guess if we allowed SMTP we wouldn't have to worry about it as much as it would be using whatever SMTP server not the webhost server.

Comment: Authenticated SMTP as the only supported mail sending route might be a good option... assuming that all of the PHP code you intend to run won't be using `mail()` at all.

Comment: Yea, these are ISP customers so its totally random what they'll use and I'm sure some of them would want to use mail().